# Compile play2-scheduled-job-demo with playframework 2.1

Tags: playframework, scheduled-tasks, background-process, web-worker, playframework-2.1

I'm working on Play Framework 2.1 application which should use Heroku worker dyno units to perform time consuming background jobs. There are some general discussions around about how to do that, but not so much practical examples.

This James Ward's example looks very close to what I want to achieve:

https://github.com/jamesward/play2-scheduled-job-demo

It is implemented for Play Framework 2.0.1, so I've carefully converted project files to the 2.1 version. Unfortunately the project doesn't compile due to the error in TickJob.java

```
package jobs;

import models.Tick;
import play.api.Play;
import play.api.Mode;
import play.api.Application;

import java.io.File;


public class TickJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application application = 
            new Application(new File(args[0]), TickJob.class.getClassLoader(), null, Mode.Prod());

        Play.start(application);

        Tick tick = new Tick("Hello from the TickJob");
        tick.save();
   }

}
```

Here is the logs of the error:

```
 TickJob.java:15: play.api.Application is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Apparently this is a consequence of changes in APIs of 2.0.1 and 2.1.0. So how can this be fixed for 2.1.0?

As far as I understand the main method in TickJob class is the entry point for the worker process. From the Procfile it is clear that TickJob is run on Heroku as a separate java application, not a play framework application. So I assume the purpose of creating the Play application in the main method here is to get access to the database of the web application and model classes.

**UPDATE**

The issue with compilation is now fixed. I was not able to run the application locally with Foreman on Windows XP, so I took the following steps to actually observe the application in action.

1. In a console type `play`, and then in play console type `$ h2-browser`. This will start h2 database in TCP server mode on `/localhost:9092/`
2. Execute the following bat script to start up play web application on port 9000 and connect it to the database

   ```
   set PORT=9000
   set DATABASE_URL=jdbc:h2:tcp:localhost:9092/mem/play

   java -Dhttp.port=%PORT% -Ddb.default.url=%DATABASE_URL% -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -cp "target/staged/*"; play.core.server.NettyServer target/..
   ```

   This is a mix of the `target/start` script produced by `play stage` command with arguments from Procfile.
3. Execute another bat script to trigger the background job process that gets connected to the same database as the web process, which is the whole point of the example

   ```
    set DATABASE_URL=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem/play

    java -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf -Ddb.default.url=%DATABASE_URL% -cp "target/staged/*"; jobs.TickJob .

    pause
   ```

Don't forget the dot at the end of the java command. It is what gets passed as `args[0]` in `new DefaultApplication(new File(args[0]), ...)` . Took me forever to figure that out).

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'll get this updated to Play 2.1 asap.

Comment: My code has been updated to Play 2.1.0.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your code examples are very useful. The answer by @nico_ekito resolved issue of compilation for 2.1. Now I'm stuck running it on Foreman in Win XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `DefaultApplication` instead of `Application`:

```
public class TickJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application application = 
            new DefaultApplication(new File(args[0]), TickJob.class.getClassLoader(), null, Mode.Prod());

        Play.start(application);

        Tick tick = new Tick("Hello from the TickJob");
        tick.save();
   }

}
```

The API can be found here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.DefaultApplication

It has been changed in the 2.1 version.